# Synching Outlook.com with Hotmail.com

Tags: sync, hotmail, outlook.com

I have both a Hotmail.com account and an Outlook.com account. Is it possible to sync contacts (People) of the two? I see an import feature (from Gmail etc.) but not from Hotmail.

Comment: Could this be helpful? http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/microsoft-office-outlook-hotmail-connector-overview-HA010222518.aspx

Comment: In order to sync the contacts I would just export your contacts.

Comment: Thanks, but this is Microsoft Office Outlook, while I am interested in the Microsoft Outlook.com mail service.

Comment: @Ramhound: Using files works, but it is not viable, as for every new contact one has to export to a file from Hotmail, import the file in Outlook.com and manage conflicts. Then again export to a file from Outlook.com, import the file to Hotmail and manage conflicts. Synching should be simpler.